# Where in the Standard does it say that every allocation returned by `new` is aligned to `std::max_align_t`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, memory-alignment

[In this video](https://youtu.be/uSZFrmhayIM?t=6m18s), at approximately 6.39, the presenter seems to say that `new` always returns memory aligned to `std::max_align_t`, which makes sense, since `operator new` doesn't know anything about the type of the variable being allocated. That is, the compiler has to opt for the strictest alignment. But I can't find this in the Standard.

The presenter also says that this rule doesn't apply when `new` is used to allocate `char` or `unsigned char` arrays. In this case, the alignment depends on the size. But this was not clear to me either.

Comment: `operator new` has a size parameter, so it has *some* info about the allocated memory. For example if you just allocate 2 bytes that memory doesn't have to be properly aligned for a `long double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in  [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/2:

> The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage. If it is successful, it shall
>   return the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes shall be at least as large as
>   the requested size. [...] **The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted
>   to a pointer of any complete object type with a fundamental alignment requirement** (3.11) and then used
>   to access the object or array in the storage allocated (until the storage is explicitly deallocated by a call
>   to a corresponding deallocation function). [...]

Comment: That's fine. But could you comment on the exception alluded by the presenter for arrays of char and unsigned chars

Comment: @Belloc: I'm pretty sure their claim is wrong, and I suspect Kerrek is implicitly saying that with his quote. Of course, the answer would be better if it said something *explicitly*.

Comment: @Belloc: No, I've not seen the talk. Perhaps this is about something else, namely the array-new *expression* (rather than the allocation function)? Array-new expressions for char types are special in that the returned pointer must be maximally aligned, not just aligned for char.